# ActionbarSherlock and homeAsUpIndicator

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have the problem to customize the back arrow. I want a red arrow instead of default arrow. I've read many topics about that but it doesn't work.

So i place my styles in res/values/styles.xml. Here is my code :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/btn_nav_retour</item>

</style>
```

I can't set "android:homeAsUpIndicator" beacause it requires api level 11 and my min sdk is 9.

Should I set the same code in res/values-v11/styles.xml ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work in all API's you should create `style.xml` in `values-v11` and `values-v14` folder. In `values-v14` for example you should use:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/btn_nav_retour</item>
</style>
```

In default `values` folder you should use attributes given by `ActionBarSherlock`, but for higher API levels you should stick with Android default `ActionBar` attributes and place `android:` in front of them. In that way it will work for higher API levels.

Comment: it's working but, the folders name which you give are wrong. The correct folders name are values-v11, values-v14.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidenote to the accepted answer:
if you don't want to duplicate your Theme for both API-ranges, you could add both items to your AppBaseTheme in values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/btn_nav_retour</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator" tools:targetApi="11">@drawable/btn_nav_retour</item>
</style>
```

The targetApi-attribute prevents the error-message from lint. The xml-item it annotates is ignored by older Android-versions.